Entity Framework Core migrations
I have a problem with migrations in EF Core. I am trying to familiarize myself with an older WPF project and I have done some restructuring. I moved my context to a class library that has the common code
namespace WPFDemoApp.Common.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext<TEntity> : DbContext where TEntity : class
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext<TEntity>> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory<TEntity> : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext<TEntity>> where TEntity : class
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext<TEntity> CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext<TEntity>>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=localdatabase.db");

            return new ApplicationDbContext<TEntity>(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}

It is registered in a different project:
namespace WPFDemoApp
{
    public static class ServiceRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            // Register services here
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext<ToDoItem>>(
            options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=localdatabase.db"));

            services.AddScoped<MainWindow>();
            services.AddScoped<ToDoItem>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<ToDoItem>, Repository<ToDoItem>>();
            services.AddScoped<IGetAllDataUseCase<ToDoItem>, GetAllDataUseCase<ToDoItem>>();
            services.AddScoped<MainViewModel<ToDoItem>>();

            // Add other services
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
}

And when I am using the

Does anyone know why?
I have tried running different commands but the older WPF structure is giving me a headache.

Why DbContext for every entity? It should be one context and many entities. Maybe i'm missing something?

You are right i wanted to try something else but it flopped , the non generic solution works :)

Using a Non-Generic DbContext for Migrations
namespace WPFDemoApp.Common.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ToDoItem> ToDoItems { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            // Apply configurations here if any
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=localdatabase.db");

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}

Modify Service Registration:
Register the non-generic ApplicationDbContext in your DI container:
namespace WPFDemoApp
{
    public static class ServiceRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            // Register services here
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=localdatabase.db"));

            services.AddScoped<MainWindow>();
            services.AddScoped<ToDoItem>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<ToDoItem>, Repository<ToDoItem>>();
            services.AddScoped<IGetAllDataUseCase<ToDoItem>, GetAllDataUseCase<ToDoItem>>();
            services.AddScoped<MainViewModel<ToDoItem>>();

            // Add other services
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
}

Run Migrations:
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Project YourProjectName -StartupProject YourStartupProjectName -Context ApplicationDbContext


So is there a reason the Generics don't work ? I did it with non early and it was fine so my guess was like the generics will work to.
